# What is the difference between these two comparisons of sets?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm comparing between set of string and set of list of string. The results appear inconsistent and are puzzling to me.

For example, while `set('3') == set(['3'])` is returning **True**, `set('003') == set(['003'])` is returning **False**.

Could anyone help to explain why is this the case?

Comment: A simple print will make this clear to you. This is the same difference as `['003']` and `list('003')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the full explanation, you can print the `set()` for every example.

```
>>>set('3')
{'3'}
>>>set(['3'])
{'3'}
>>>set('003')
{0, 3}
>>>set(['003'])
{'003'}
```

`set('003')` the string is a list of characters, that is why it unzipped it and added 0 and 3 as items. `set(['003'])` here the list has on item which is the `003`, so it will unzip this item and add it.

`set()` will unzip the list items and add them as its items. For more in deep info please read the [offical docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Comment: Thanks Emad for outlining the train of thought in a very clear and concise manner! Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

`set('003')` creates an entry for every unique item in that **`string`** (`list` of `chars`), so it returns `{'3', '0'}` and it's equal to `set(['0','0','3'])`.

While `set(['003'])` creates an entry for each item of the **`list`**, so it returns `{'003'}`

Answer (score 1):

Because `set(['003'])` returns `{'003'}`, and `set('003')` - `{'0', '3'}`.

Answer (score 1):

First case:

```
>>> set('3') == set(['3'])
True
>>> set('3')
{'3'}
>>> set(['3'])
{'3'}
```

Second case:

```
>>> set('003') == set(['003'])
False
>>> set('003')
{'0','3'}
>>> set(['003'])
{'003'}
```

When you pass strings to `tuple`, `set`, `list` etc. each character of the string is viewed as one element of that data structure. As you may know, `set` are collection of unordered, unique elements. So when you call `set` on `'003'`, it is creating a set, and tries putting one character at a time in that set. First character would be `0`, then `3`, then another `3`, but as their is repetition, one of the `3`s is ignored. So you get: `{'0','3'}`. In case of a `string` inside a `list`, the entire string is viewed as an element, so the set gets only one element, that is `{'003'}`.

---

You can check a few more examples:

```
>>> tuple('abc')
('a','b','c')
>>> list('abc')
['a','b','c']
```